# Finding dangling else in c++ code

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have just been made aware of the [dangling else problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) and I worry that I might have done this many more times in my code.

Is there any good way to find all dangling else in my c++ code? (cppcheck or regular expression does not seam to work)

Comment: Avoid the problem by using braces in complex if statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gcc this is caught by the warning flag `-Wparentheses`, which actually catches several different things.

In clang it has its own flag `-Wdangling-else`.